# Build Docker image with specific folder context using circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1 orb

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have a repo with this structure:

```
repo
├── app1
│   ├── app
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── Dockerfile
├── app2
│   ├── app
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── Dockerfile
├── app3
│   ├── app
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── Dockerfile
```

Let's say that I want to build image of app1

`app1/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev libffi-dev

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

RUN rm requirements.txt

COPY app .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["script.py"]
```

My CircleCI file is:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  docker: circleci/docker@2.2.0
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@03.2.0

[...]

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          platform: linux/arm64
          path: app1
```

During the CI build, I got this error:

```
> [7/7] COPY app .:
------
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/app" not found: not found
```

It seems that during the build, the build context is `repo` and not `app1`. I saw that there is an [argument](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecr#commands-build-and-push-image) `build-path` with this orb but when I do :

```
workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          platform: linux/arm64
          path: app1
          build-path: app1
```

I got this error:
`Error calling job: 'aws-ecr/build-and-push-image' Unexpected argument(s): build-path`

How can I specify the build context path with this orb?

Comment: build-path is an argument on the command and not job.
Which is why you're getting that last error, i would presume.

I'd be interested to know if anyone knows why there is no build-path on the job.

Comment: Ok thank you and indeed I find this really strange that they don't provide an argument for the job